# Send a message to Telegram

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I want this code to send a message to Telegram every minute, but it only works when the code is stopped:

```py
import asyncio
import telegram
import time


bot_token = 'xxx'
chat_id = 'xxx'


bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)

async def send_message():
  
    current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    current_date = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

 
    message = f'الوقت الحالي: {current_time}\nالتاريخ الحالي: {current_date}'

   
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

while True:
    asyncio.create_task(send_message())

   
    time.sleep(60)
```

The code runs without errors, but the message is not sent until the code is stopped.

Comment: I highly recommend to read some general tutorials on `asyncio`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem replace the `while` block with:

```py
async def main():
    while True:
        await send_message()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)


asyncio.run(main())
```

To learn more about `asincio` I suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).